# EX4200-48T power Consumption

Tags: juniper

I read Juniper documents but i could not find how much power does Juniper EX4200-48T consume?
can anyone help me?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PSU is rated with 320 W. 130 W for PoE and 190 W for the switch itself.

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/hardware/ex4200/ex4200.pdf

Note that these are the maximum power draws for power/UPS sizing. For calculating a cooling budget you might want to use an average power in your scenario.

Comment: one question, 320w is the max power consumption? if I disable poe it will use only 190w?

Comment: Yes, 320 W is the maximum possible power. PoE devices (PD) draw addtional power from the switch, up to 130 W. Without any PD connected, 190 W is the max. Actively disabling PoE shouldn't make much of a difference but with a tight power budget you might want to do so.

Comment: so if even i disable PoE on the switch it will draw 130w from the switch? is there anyway to stop this action ? disable poe or some kind of treak?

Comment: *Without any PD connected, 190 W is the max.*

Comment: greats, port 0-7 in 48t are PoE ports if i connect servers to these ports and do not use poe power then the switch take 190w max , right?

Comment: Yes. It only matters how much power is drawn from the PoE ports by an PoE-powered device, not whether they are used or not.